# USB-C charger not working (MBP 2017)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery, charger

My 61W charger doesn't charge my MBP 2017. But when I charge with my friend's apple charger it works. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't charge". Is the charger detected at all? Does the charging icon change? Does it provide enough power to turn the computer on?

Comment: Try a different USB-C cable.  I typically don't use the one's Apple supplies because they are very cheap (low quality).  I use [Anker braided USB-C cables](https://amzn.to/2Is85dD) because of their high quality and lifetime warranty.  If this new cable doesn't work, it's your charger.  You need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a **guess** as you've not mentioned the cables you're using, but:

Could it be that you're using a [`non e-Marked` USB C cable?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) If so, the cable may be the problem. Try *your* charger with your *friend's* cable to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Either your 61W charger or your USB-C charging cable is probably defective. If you can visit an Apple Store, they can help you test it.

But you've already done the most important test -- tried two identical model chargers with the same laptop and got different results. One other test you might want to try is pairing your charger with your friend's laptop. Another test is swapping cables only.

Comment: The OP never mentions the model of his friends charger so saying "they're identical" is a guess.  However, a lower spec charger *will* charge, albeit, slowly.  There's no need to visit an Apple store.  Either the charger is bad or it's the cable.  It's easy to test this theory with a known working cable.